# Change an AbstractAction name

Tags: java, swing, label, jmenuitem, abstract-action

I have a JMenuItem bounded to an Action that I can get using `item.getAction()`. The action name is set when constructing the Action, e.g. using anonymous `new AbstractAction(String text, ...)`. The text field is set according to a ResourceBundle and localization information. Now if I want to change localization, I would like to change the Action.NAME field so that it displays the proper localized name. I can only get the name, e.g. using `item.getAction().NAME` but cannot change the field as it is final.

How could I change it's name?

Comment: please why `cbut cannot change the field as it is final.`c , isn't possible to create that as local variable

Comment: `Action#NAME` is a key used by the `Action` to store a value which other components can use as a display value (by using `Action#getValue(Action.NAME)`).  You can change the name by using `putValue` of the action, using `Action.NAME` as the key and the text as the name you want to use.  Take a close look at [Using Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The final field is actually the key for the name property of the action. Change the name property using `putValue()`

```
action.putValue(Action.NAME, newName);
```

Comment: Is it normal that action.getValue(Action.NAME) returns null at first, while the name is not null? The actual name is given by getActionCommand()

Comment: It depends, if the subclass uses the contructor that specifies a name, it should not be null. But a subclass may also override `getValue()` and `putValue()`, so no guarantees there.